Websocket client not able to listen to WebSocket's sendText method from FastAPI
I am trying to listen for messages from backend using FastAPI and react.js on frontend. I am able to send message to backend from client and also able to receive to broadcast messages from backend to client. The issue occurs for sending personal message to a particular client for which I am not able to listen to it on client side. I don't see any error from backend as well as client side
Here is my backend code
class ConnectionManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.active_connections: list[WebSocket] = []

    async def connect(self, websocket: WebSocket):
        await websocket.accept()
        self.active_connections.append(websocket)

    def disconnect(self, websocket: WebSocket):
        self.active_connections.remove(websocket)

    async def send_personal_message(self, message: str, websocket: WebSocket):
        print("hereeeee")
        await websocket.send_text(message)
        print("hereeeee11111")

    async def broadcast(self, message: str):
        for connection in self.active_connections:
            await connection.send_text(message)


app = FastAPI()

origins = ["http://localhost:3000"]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],    
)

manager = ConnectionManager()

@app.websocket("/ws/{client_id}")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket, client_id: int):
    await manager.connect(websocket)
    try:
        while True:

            data = await websocket.receive_text()
            await manager.send_personal_message(f"You wrote: {data}", websocket)
            
    except WebSocketDisconnect:
        manager.disconnect(websocket)
        await manager.broadcast(f"Client #{client_id} left the chat")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app,port=8000,host="127.0.0.1")

Here is my frontend react.js code
export default function Home() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const [messages, setMessage] = useState<string[]>([]);
  var client_id = Date.now();
  const socket = new WebSocket(`ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/${client_id}`);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.onopen = function (event) {
      console.log("Connected to WebSocket server");
    };

    socket.onmessage = function (event) {
      console.log("Received message:", event);
      setMessage((oldArray) => [...oldArray, event.data]);
    };

    socket.onclose = function (event) {
      console.log("WebSocket connection closed");
    };
  }, []);

  const onChangeHandler = (event: any) => {
    setInput(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
      <input type="text" onChange={onChangeHandler} value={input} />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          console.log("here");
          socket.send(input);
        }}>
        Submit
      </button>
      {messages.map((item, index) => {
        return <h5 key={`${index}`}>{item}</h5>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

Now in my backend code if I replace await manager.send_personal_message(f"You wrote: {data}", websocket) with await manager.broadcast(f"Client #{client_id} says: {data}") then I am able to listen to backend messages but does not work for await manager.send_personal_message(f"You wrote: {data}", websocket) as in my case I don't want to broadcast to all the users but send it to a particular user's client id
